# Can I make input fields dynamically change in Shiny based on other inputs?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app in R with several inputs (drop-downs and sliders). Initially they all have default values for when the app opens, using the "selected" parameter.

But, i'm wondering if there is way to dynamically change the default value based on a certain input field.

Example, if I have one input field that is a drop-down of ***countries*** and then I have one slider input of ***price for a pint of beer***. As a default "Ireland" is selected from the countries list and the slider is defaulted to €5.00. Now what I want is if I select "Poland" from the countries list the slider would then change to €2.00.

Is this possible and how?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Yes, this is generally possible, but please add your reproducible example to help us help you.

Comment: You can also use `updateSliderInput()` for that instead of re-building a new input every time

Comment: You can create UI elements in the server using `renderUI`. There you can make a function that looks at the `selectInput` value and then returns a slider Input for example. In the UI you display it with `uiOutput`.